# adding 'weight' to a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I work in customer service center where we monitor calls and grade them.

We have an excel sheet where we score these calls, and my question is, we want to give a greater weight fro 10 points an agent can get for opening of the call rather than 15 points he can get for questions he asked.

Is there such function in excel?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can add the weight to the value and get a new column, "weighted value." The function is SUM(...), although you can also use a + in an equation.

Comment: I do not think I explained myself clearly maybe. Call opening and it points need to have bigger importance than questioning, so in case agent loses points form opening the overall score will be lower thank if he loses the same value for questioning.

Comment: So you have a score in column A. Have a column, B, called weight. Add the score plus the weight to get the weighted value in column C. Make the weight bigger for call opening and negative for questioning. Your next step, which you haven't asked, would be to create a pivot table that calculates average weighted value by employee.

Answer (score 1):

#### We need to see some example data how it is now, and how you want it to look to help you better.

Although lets say you You have a Score in Column B and the Weight in Column C, you can add the score and the weight and then compare that to the sum of all scores and weights to get a percentage of 100 compared to the group.

As follows,

> `A1="Call or Question"` ▬ `B1="Score"` ▬ `C1="Weight"` ▬ `D1="Weighted Score"`
>
> `A2:A↓ =CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"Question","Call")`
>
> `B2:B↓ =RANDBETWEEN(25,75)`
>
> `C2:C↓ =IF(A2="Call",15,IF(A2="Question",-10,0))`
>
> `D2:D↓ =(B2+C2)/SUM(B:C)`

The best part of this is that the Weighted Score Column will sum up to be 100%.

-I hope this helps in any way.